# Rings and Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

I have a few questions in ring and fields theory.

First of all, I was trying to show that the field of quotients of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{12}}{\langle 4 \rangle}$ is exactly itself, once it is a field.
Is easy once $\langle 4 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ has unity and is commutative, then this quotient is a field.
Is this right?

The second question is, why cannot exist a integral domain with 10 elements?

Comment: `is exactly this object`: which object?

Comment: Pardon, "this object" refers to the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_{12}/\langle 4\rangle$.

Comment: Note that quotient structures in algebra are always notated with a slash, never with a fraction bar.

Comment: In the future, if you have separate questions, please ask them separately, not in the same post. And please make your title reflect exactly what you are asking. This post is low-quality in general; later visitors to this site are not likely to search for "rings and fields" and get an answer to their question by clicking on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost feel this must be wrong, since it seems so obvious and nobody else has pointed it out, but:

Actually $\langle 4\rangle$ is not a maximal ideal. And in fact the quotient $\Bbb Z_{12}/\langle 4\rangle$ is not even an integral domain, since $2(2)=0$.

Comment: And because of this cannot have quotient field?

Comment: I'm not _certain_ what you mean by "quotient field". It certainly cannot have a field of quotients. Because $2$ would have a multiplicative inverse...

Comment: I am sorry, I used the wrong terminology, I was trying to say "field of quotients".

Answer (score 4):

The prime ideals of $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$  are the images  by the canonical map $\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$ of the prime ideals of $\mathbf Z$ which contain $12$, i.e. they are $\;2\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$  and $\;3\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$.

An elementary proof that a finite domain $A$ has a number of elements that is a prime power:

Consider the  ring homomorphism $\;c\colon\mathbf Z\to A$, $\;n\mapsto n\cdot 1_A$. As $A$ is finite, $\ker c=r\mathbf Z, r\neq 0$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $\;\mathbf Z/r\mathbf Z$  is isomorphic to a subring of $A$, hence  it is an integral domain, and $r$ is prime.

Now $\mathbf Z/r\mathbf Z$  is a finite field with $r$ elements, and $A$ is a finite dimensional vector space over that field, say it has dimension $n$. This implies $A$ has $r^n$ elements.

*Note*: it is very easy to prove a finite integral domain is a field: to show each $a\ne 0$ has an inverse in $A$, consider the multiplication-by-$a$ endomorphism of $A$. As $A$ is an integral domain, this homomorphism is injective (this means $a$ is not a zero-divisor on $A$). But as $A$ is finite, for any map from $A$ to $A$, injective $\iff$ surjective. Hence $1$ is attained by this multiplication, i.e. $a$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, as shown in the answer by David C. Ullrich.
2. By [Wedderburn's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn's_little_theorem).

Comment: I am sorry but, how the fact that a finite integral domain is a field implies that it can not has 10 elements?

Comment: Because a finite field is a linear space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Therefore, every finite field has $p^n$ elements, $p$ prime.